# How can i remove the sidebar in movable type?

Tags: movabletype

im building a new side with movable type. And i want to remove the sidebar for a few pages, but not for all the pages.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the archive template -> page

`<mt:Var name="hide_sidebar" value="1">`

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

More in depth answer....

This code sets the variable `hide_sidebar` to `1`:

```
<mt:Var name="hide_sidebar" value="1">
```

The sidebar in the classic blog template set is wrapped in the following conditional code which will have no output if `hide_sidebar` is set to `1`:

```
<mt:Unless name="hide_sidebar">
    <!-- sidebar code here -->
</mt:Unless>
```

This solution can be manually added to any template set, but this code can be found in the Classic Blog template set that ships with MT 4.x.

More about the [MT If conditional](http://movabletype.org/tag/if) and which is related to the unless conditional

(I can't link to any other resources as I need more reputation points.)